HTML infinitly sidescrolling images move unexpected
I'm currently working on this HTML website, in which there is a container with images, which are supposed to infinitely scroll horizontaly, but with my logic they move a bit further or a bit less then they are supposed to.
Code snippet:


var allowNewMovement = true;

function moveProject(direction, parent) {
  if (allowNewMovement) {
    var leftPositions = [];
    let i = 0;

    // Speichere die initialen Positionen
    for (const child of parent.children) {
      leftPositions.push(child.offsetLeft);
    }

    if (direction == 'left') {
      for (const child of parent.children) {
        if (i >= 1) {
          child.style.left = leftPositions[i - 1] + "px";
        } else {
          child.style.left = leftPositions[leftPositions.length - 1] + "px";
        }
        if (child.offsetLeft == 0) {
          child.style.opacity = "0";
          setTimeout(() => {
            child.style.opacity = "1"
          }, 600);
        }
        i++;
      }
    } else {
      for (const child of parent.children) {
        if (i < leftPositions.length - 1) {
          child.style.left = leftPositions[i + 1] + "px";
        } else {
          child.style.left = leftPositions[0] + "px";
        }
        if (child.offsetLeft == Math.max(Math.max(...leftPositions.filter(pos => typeof pos === 'number')))) {
          child.style.opacity = "0";
          setTimeout(() => {
            child.style.opacity = "1"
          }, 600);
        }
        i++;
      }
    }
    allowNewMovement = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      allowNewMovement = true
    }, 500)
  }
}
.projectContainer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 70vh;
  left: -50vw;
}

.project {
  position: relative;
  height: 70vh;
}

.img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 47vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-left: 2vw;
  white-space: normal;
  transition: left 0.5s;
}

#left {
  left: 55vw;
}

#right {
  left: 145vw;
}

#right,
#left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 3vh;
  width: 3vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 5;
}
<div class="projectContainer">
  <div id="project8" class="project">
    <p class="img">Project Description</p>
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
    <img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img">
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JpbbB6V2.png" id="left" onclick="moveProject('right', document.getElementById('project8'))">
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/6HqVMRmB.png" id="right" onclick="moveProject('left', document.getElementById('project8'))">
</div>



This is obviously not the full code, but if you need more code for an answer, please contact me.
I already tried to figure out how big the difference is, but it was relative to the viewport size and the images are relative to the viewport size, which screwed everything up (I think).
Thanks for an answer!

Here's the fix:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Initialize Slick Carousel when DOM is ready
  $('#project8 .carousel').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    prevArrow: '<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JpbbB6V2.png" id="left">',
    nextArrow: '<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/6HqVMRmB.png" id="right">',
responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 430,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                }
            }
        ]
  });
});
#right,
#left {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#right {
  right: 0px;
}

#left {
  left: 0px;
}
<!-- JQuery: -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slick Carousel CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
<div class="projectContainer">
  <div id="project8" class="project">
    <div class="carousel">
      <div><img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img"></div>
      <div><img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img"></div>
      <div><img alt="Projektbild" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img"></div>
      <!-- Add more carousel items as needed -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Slick Carousel JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>



For this, I used Slick. You can take out the containing divs, and then the images will be full screen.
